# How to multiply all values in a javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a form with multiple textboxes and number of textboxes do change depending on the values I retrieve from the database. What I am trying to do is multiply all values of textfields values so first I put them into an array and multiply them and send the answer to a textbox. But I cant seem to get the right answer.

For example when I have 3 textboxes and I enter 1 to each text box I should get 1x1x1 = 1 but I get answer as 3. An when I enter 2 in each text box I should get 2x2x2 = 8 but answer is 12.

My code is as follows:

Javascript Code:

```
function sumfrm(form){ 
  var totalOdds = 0;
  var odds = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var n;
  var i; //
for (i = 0; i < odds.length; ++i) {
  n = parseFloat(odds.item(i).value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
       totalOdds += n*n;
   }
}
```

Comment: totalOdds += n*n; does the following: it takes the result of n*n and adds it to totalOdds. (You want something like: totalOdds = totalOdds * n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var totalOdds = 1; //initialize like this
totalOdds = totalOdds * n // do this in your for loop
```

should do the trick

What you currently have for 1x1x1.

`totalOdds` in the begining is 0

After 
`totalOdds += 1 * 1`

is 1

Again after second time
`totalOdds += 1 * 1`

is 2

and after third time it is **3**

Comment: The reason why this works and not your original code, is that in the for loop you are taking totalOdds and adding n*n (n squared).  What you want to do instead is start with 1, multiply that by input box 1, then multiply the result by each input box in turn.  totalOdds *= n is another way to accomplish that

Comment: @LondonBoy ... Glad it was of help. Please accept it as an answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < odds.length; ++i) {
    n = parseFloat(odds.item(i).value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        totalOdds *= n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumfrm(form){ 
  var totalOdds = 1; // changed
  var odds = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var n;
  var i; //
for (i = 0; i < odds.length; ++i) {
  n = parseFloat(odds.item(i).value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
       totalOdds *= n; // changed
   }
}
```

Changed two lines. It should work correctly now, brother :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you a little bit code cleanup:

1. remove the unused `form` argument from your function.
2. Reduce the number of local variables in your function body.

   ```
   function multiply() {

       var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

       var result = parseFloat(inputs.item(0).value, 10) || 0;
       (result == 0) && return 0;
       for (var i = 1; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
           n = parseFloat(inputs.item(i).value, 10);
           (isNaN(n) || n == 0) ? return 0 : result *= n;
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the sum of the squares of the numbers. Instead, do this:

```
function sumfrm(form){ 
  var totalOdds = 1;
  var odds = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var n, i;
  for(i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {
    n = parseFloat(odds[i].value);
    if(!isNaN(n)) {
       totalOdds *= n;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to do array multiply it will be better to use default function in java script "reduce", u can push all the values to an array and then do the multiplication
Please try the below code. (it is ES6)

```
let sum = [1, 1, 1].reduce( (prev, curr) => prev * curr );
```